# Failure in coordinate transformation for projecting global position in camera coordinate frame

Tags: python, linear-algebra, transformation, robotics, back-projection

For a project I'm working on I have written a function which should take position and rotation in global coordinate frame of a robot and a camera, and project the postion of the robot into the camera coordinate image pane.
The intrinsics of the camera are described by a 3x3 calibration camera K
The offset of the robot camera from the imu of the robot is described by the 4x4 transformation matrix spot_T_imu_cam (transformation from camera to imu)
The same is with the offset of the camera, using the transformation matrix HL_T_imu_cam.
This transformation runs, but the results don't appear to be correct. I am looking for something I might have missed.

```
Id = np.append(np.identity(3), np.matrix([0,0,0]).T, axis=1)
import pytransform3d.transformations as pytr
from pytransform3d.transformations import invert_transform
def get_projected_point(pq_spot, pq_HL, p=[0., 0., 0.]):
    T_G_spot = pytr.transform_from_pq(pq_spot)
    T_G_HL = pytr.transform_from_pq(pq_HL)

    T_HL_spot = invert_transform(HL_T_imu_cam) @ invert_transform(T_G_HL) @ (T_G_spot) @ (spot_T_imu_cam)
    p_in_HL_frame = T_HL_spot @ np.array([p[0], p[1], p[2], 1.])[:, None]
    assert p_in_HL_frame[3] == 1.

    point2d = K @ Id @ p_in_HL_frame

    # point2d = point2d/point2d[2]
    # assert point2d[2] == 1.

    # point2d = K @ p_in_HL_frame[:3]

    
    return point2d

point2d = get_projected_point(pq1,pq2)
ax.scatter([point2d[0]], [point2d[1]], color='red')
point2d = get_projected_point(pq1,pq2, p=[0, 0, -1])
ax.scatter([point2d[0]], [point2d[1]], color='green')
```

In my current attempts I have tried double-checking the transformation matrices I use, as well as re-recording the input global positions. Neither has worked